# Why might a resource request be slow only when requested by a page?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, networking

I have a webpage that pulls in a ~500kb JPG that takes around 11s in the Content Download phase (in the Chrome Network tab).

What is strange is that if I access that same resource on a tab of its own or via curl, it downloads in less than a second.

I've even made sure that I'm including all the headers and cookies that the page uses.

Are there any mechanisms that limit throughput for page requests that would manifest in this way? Any suggestions about what could result in this behaviour?

Comment: Are you loading other resources from the same server? There is a limit on how many resources the browser will load concurrently from a single host.

Comment: Yes, but how would that affect Content Download time? My understanding is that limit is on the number of concurrent downloads from one domain (which would impact queueing time). Is there a bandwidth limit also?

Comment: No you're right, the content download phase in chrome means the data is being retrieved right now. Perhaps other resources being downloaded concurrently reduce the available bandwidth? Chrome goes up to 6 concurrent connections to a single source.

Comment: Other possible explanation (no source that's just an idea to explore): the thread that manages the transfer gets blocked by some other synchronous task.